# What is the Julia MethodError?

Tags: package, julia, grammar

I am trying to create a function that corrects the grammar of a string, but it generates a MethodError saying no method matching ::Colon. Is there some problem with the package or am I using it wrong? I am using the EnglishText package.

My code

```
julia> using EnglishText

julia> function grmr(s)
       ws = split(s, " ")
       ss = ""
       for i in 1:size(ws)
       if parse(Int64, ws[i])
       ws[i + 1] = ItemQuantity(parse(Int64, ws[i]), ws[i + 1])
       ws[i] = ""
       elseif ws[i] in ["many", "multiple", "numerous", "several", "few", "some"]
       ws[i + 1] = pluralize(singularize(ws[i + 1]))
       elseif ws[i] in ["single", "a", "an"]
       ws[i + 1] = singularize(ws[i + 1])
       elseif split(ws[i])[end] == "s"
       ws[i] = pluralize(singularize(ws[i]))
       elseif ws[i] in ["a", "an"]
       ws[i] = indefinite(ws[i + 1])
       end
       ss = string(ss, ws[i], " ")
       end
       return ss
       end
grmr (generic function with 1 method)

julia> grmr("I have 2 apple")
```

The error

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching (::Colon)(::Int64, ::Tuple{Int64})
Closest candidates are:
  (::Colon)(::T, ::Any, ::T) where T<:Real at range.jl:41
  (::Colon)(::A, ::Any, ::C) where {A<:Real, C<:Real} at range.jl:10
  (::Colon)(::T, ::Any, ::T) where T at range.jl:40
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] grmr(s::String)
   @ Main .\REPL[2]:4
 [2] top-level scope
   @ REPL[3]:1
```

Those are the only lines of code in the directory.

"I have 2 apple" was supposed to become I have 2 apples, but it gave the error instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `size(ws)` is a tuple. You want `1:length(ws)` or `1:size(ws)[1]`.